# How to schedule multiple tasks using celery beat in Python?

Tags: python, flask, celery, celerybeat

I have a function and I've created a task using celery in flask, the task runs every minute of the day. I have created another 3 tasks for the same function- these tasks run on some days at some time, every day at a fixed time. I tried running all these tasks but it ran only the first tasks I had created (which is running every minute of the day).

Here's a snippet of my code:
the function:

```
@celery.task(name='scheduler',once={'graceful': True})
def scheduler(self):
    #rest of the code
```

celery configurations:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
app = Flask(__name__)
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
def make_celery(app):
    #Celery configuration
    app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    app.config['CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE'] = {
        # Executes every minute
        'periodic_task-every-minute': {
            'task': 'scheduler',
            'schedule': crontab(minute="*"),
            'args': (1,2)
        },
        'periodic_task-every-friday':{
            'task': 'scheduler',
            'schedule': crontab(day_of_week='friday',hour=0,minute=10),
            'args': (3,4)
        },
        'periodic_task-every-monday':{
            'task':'scheduled_scheduling',
            'schedule': crontab(day_of_week='monday',hour=20,minute=20),
            'args': (5,6)
        },
        'periodic_task-daily':{
            'task': 'scheduler',
            'schedule': crontab(hour=20,minute=20),
            'args':(7,8)
        }
    }

    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery(app)
```

The task which runs is only 'periodic-task-every-minute' whereas the rest don't run.

Comment: Did you wait for Monday 20:20 or Friday 0:10 to make sure these periodic tasks run?

Comment: @DejanLekic for Monday I did wait and as far as Friday 0:10 is concerned i changed it for Tuesday 12:30 but these tasks were not running..only one single task was running which was running every minute of the day.